# Transitions are triggerd for changes made befor adding transition specific css properties. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Take a look at this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zB2Td/5/

Animation is triggered although `.animate`  class is added after changing the dimensions.
If you uncomment the second line from the end transition won't start as it should.
Why does this code work like that?
What is a proper way to add `.animate` and not trigger transition on the previous changes.
Thanks!

Comment: I think that happen because when width() is execute set the with based of css (200), and the animation work but do not is visible (because we haven't transition from 100 to 200), to test try: box.width('400') and the animation is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, what's happening is that the call to `box.width()` counts as a "Read" operation, as defined by [this post](http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html). It forces the browser (webkit anyway) to re-layout (aka reflow) the DOM. Without this call, the browser never "knows" that the box was 200x200 prior to `.animate` being added, and it assumes the box started out at 100x100.